# How to make the EntityManager run SQL in the same order I invoked it?

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, jpa, jdbc, entitymanager

While developing my Java EE application I've encountered two situations in which my entities were prematurely created in the DB; They were inserted before their referenced rows were inserted, resulting in a violation of a foreign key.

At first I thought I got it wrong, creating the rows in the DB in the wrong order.
But no, this was not the case. Then I started thinking there are bugs in my JPA provider*, or maybe they just got it wrong.
But then I realised that the EntityManager wasn't aware of the connection between the tables.

Let me explain:
In both situtation table A references table B using a foreign key.

#### Situtation #1:

```
My code:
 1. Creates an entity of table B.
 2. Creates a row of table A using JDBC (there's no entity for table A).  
JPA provider:
 1. Runs the JDBC first (inserts a row into table A).
 2. SQLException is thrown, because B isn't created yet.
```

Why use JDBC?
Because it's not my code.

#### Situtation #2:

```
My code:
 1. Creates an entity of table B.
 2. Creates an entity of table A. The thing is, A only holds B's ID.
JPA provider:
 1. Creates entity A.
 2. SQLException is thrown, because B isn't created yet.
```

Why B doesn't have A as a member?
Because B has a big blob in it, and it takes a lot of memory, and I want to minimize references to B objects.

I need a solution. Maybe there's someway to tell the EntityManager to run the SQL exactly in the same order I invoked it.
While in the toilets I also thought about using 'flush' after creating entity B, but I can't test it now because our developement DB is down for maintenance (DBA working their magic).

* I'm using TopLink which comes with Oracle WebLogic 12.1.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good way to solve is to have relationship between A and B. What can be done to make that more efficient is:

- Make relationship from A to B lazy ([FetchType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html).LAZY)
- Make blob field in B lazy
- When only reference to B is needed, use [EntityManager.getReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29).

If because of some reason that cannot be done, then you should flush entitymanager after each operation that is required to be done before later operations.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot define the relationship, you can use a DescriptorCustomizer and call the API addConstraintDependency() to let EclipseLink know of the constraint, then it will issue the SQL in the correct order.